# Create table with inner join sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, create-table

I have to create a table using inner join. However, I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'" when I use the following code.

```
CREATE TABLE T1 AS
    SELECT Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.Cpr, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.Ansvarlig, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.YdelseStartdato, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.YdelseSlutdato, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.Ydelsestype, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.LeveresAf, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.Udgiftstekst, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.InstantieretPaaBagrundAf, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.DinBruger, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.Pris , Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.PrisEnhed, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.PrisIAlt, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.Effektuering, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.EffektueringFrekvens 
    FROM Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse
    inner join Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup
    ON Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.Cpr = Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.Cpr and Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.Ansvarlig = Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.Ansvarlig and Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.YdelseStartdato = Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.YdelseStartdato
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL is just the query language and the various products have different "dialects" of SQL to do certain things - like this, creating a table from a `SELECT` statement

Comment: Is it possible to use a table alias? Might not fix your issue but would make it way more readable

Comment: I´m using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre].. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `SELECT INTO` statement

```
SELECT Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.Cpr, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.Ansvarlig, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.YdelseStartdato, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.YdelseSlutdato, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.Ydelsestype, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.LeveresAf, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.Udgiftstekst, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.InstantieretPaaBagrundAf, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.DinBruger, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.Pris , Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.PrisEnhed, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.PrisIAlt, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.Effektuering, Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.EffektueringFrekvens 
INTO T1
FROM Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse
INNER JOIN Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup
ON Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.Cpr = Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.Cpr and Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.Ansvarlig = Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.Ansvarlig and Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_hovedydelse.YdelseStartdato = Deliveries.SAS_DUBU.sag_ydelse_sup.YdelseStartdato
```

You need to make sure that T1 doesn't exist before you execute this statement.

This is TSQL dialect.